# Catching the Traceback on KeyboardInterrupt()

Tags: python

I have a code that I use to stop on Ctrl+C. I would like to do some things juste after i did Ctrl+C. Therefore I write:

```
try:
    work()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    do_other_stuff()
```

But I don't see where I did Ctrl+C, as no Traceback prints; I want to see the usual message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "X.py", line 16, in <module>
         ...
```

How can I print this? I tried to do

```
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
       print str(e)
       do_other_stuff()
```

but it prints nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys, traceback
def func():
    try:
        work()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        do_something()
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

if `file` is omitted then the output goes to `stderr`.
for more on traceback...  https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html

Comment: You were faster..., but I would prefer to print to stderr (default), since that is the where a traceback belongs

Comment: Why would you do this and import two modules instead of working with `except ... as e`?

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
try:
    while True:
        x = 1
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    print 'Here we are, in the error handler!'
    raise e
```

Just make sure you run `do_other_stuff()` before you call `raise e`.

Comment: It does not work, it's just saying that there is an error on the line "raise e"

Comment: Works just fine for me.  What version of Python are you using, and what is the error?

Comment: Hmm it gives me "Traceback (most recent call last): //
  File "X.py", line 51, in <module> //
    raise e //
KeyboardInterrupt //" (and so I don't know where in my function i did stop)

Comment: Yes, that's the error content of `e` when you do a KeyboardInterrupt.  I'll add a line so you can see.  If you did, say, `except TypeError as e:` then wrote code that raised a TypeError, then doing `raise e` would print out your TypeError.  `e` has a number of other attributes, you can see in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

`KeyboardInterrupt` inherit from `BaseException`, in `BaseException` you can get the line of the error using the `traceback.format_exc(e)`.

Comment: Indeed, I have to use the traceback package but with another function!

Comment: If you like to print yes, use print_exc()

Comment: Ohh yes, using a print of course... it works, thanks!